# Split by regex vs multiple one char splits performance

Tags: java, performance, split, jmh

I compared splitting string by regex and by multiple one char splits, using this benchmark

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {
    static String start = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. 9. 10. 11. 12.";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }

    @Fork(value = 1, warmups = 0)
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @Warmup(iterations = 0)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    public static void splitByRegex() {
        String test = start;

        test = String.join("_", test.split("[1,.]"));
    }

    @Fork(value = 1, warmups = 0)
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @Warmup(iterations = 0)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    public static void multipleSplitByOneChar() {
        String test = start;

        test = String.join("_", test.split("\\."));
        test = String.join("_", test.split(","));
        test = String.join("_", test.split("1"));
    }
}
```

and got these results

```
Benchmark                    Mode  Cnt      Score     Error  Units
Test.multipleSplitByOneChar  avgt    5  10493,118 ± 572,528  ns/op
Test.splitByRegex            avgt    5  15519,418 ± 913,220  ns/op
```

Why splitting by regex is slower than splitting by multiple individual characters, even though they produce the same result?

Note:

1. I ran the code on JDK 14.0.2
2. I used JMH 1.28

Comment: I'm not an expert on benchmarking and can't say anything about how accurate your results are, but just assuming they are: Why would you expect 2 different things to take the same time just because they have the same result? Walking east 1 meter or walking west the earth circumference minus 1 meter will have the same result as well, but you don't expect those 2 operations to take the same time.

Comment: I didn't expect the same result. I thought splitting by expression would be faster. I'm interested in understanding the difference.

Comment: What's your test setup? (because this is not standa-alone Java code, and won't compile as presented), and remember to put that information in your post, don't add it as a comment =)

Comment: imports, and also which version of java, and anything else you're doing that isn't just a plain `javac Yourfile.java` followed by `java Yourfile`.

Comment: Your JMH params look suspect. NO warmups at all? To be clear, they __all__ split by regex; `.split()` takes a regexp, period. The `splitByRegex` method seems, at casual glance, to be faster, given that it involves less string manipulation. JMH results ordinarily beat reckoning, especially when performance is involved, but I'd doublecheck those JMH params first.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This _IS_ stand-alone. You just need JMH, which is a microbenchmark harness. Any question that involves 'this code runs faster than this code' and does not use JMH or something similar is worthless. OP in fact put in the effort, this is an excellent question.

Comment: @rzwitserloot just ran a program with 5 warm-ups of 5 iterations for both methods. Nothing changed. The difference is about 5 seconds.

Comment: @rzwitserloot yes, after being asked to edit their post because it lacked most details, they did, and it became a much better post. At the time of the comment, none of that information was there, and so kudos to vszholobov for adding all of that in when asked to.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Ah, of course, I should have checked the last edit stamp vs. your comment. Well, glad you asked for the details :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String.split` implementation has the optimized [fast path](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ad92033fccbf4ec9310ea5b3024be61c082ee5bb/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L3095) for splitting by one character.

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
    /* fastpath if the regex is a
     * (1) one-char String and this character is not one of the
     *     RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or
     * (2) two-char String and the first char is the backslash and
     *     the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.
     */
```